# macro producing wrong number

Tags: c, macros

I can't understand why the following code prints 2 instead of 1...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ABS(x) ((x) < 0) ? -(x) : (x)
int main()
{
    printf("%d", ABS(ABS(-2)-(ABS(-3))));
    return 0;
}
```

This question was on our exam and I answered the output is 1 but after compiling I get 2... Would anyone please explain what the expression actually do... Thanks in advance.

Comment: I write it mistakenly... It is return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with parentheses. If you expand the macro, you will get a complex nested ternary operations, which evaluate to `2` (See the expansion in the update). In order to get a desirable result surround the macro with parenthesis.

**Update**: The manual expansion:

```
ABS(ABS(-2)-(ABS(-3)))
```

expands to:

```
((ABS(-2)-(ABS(-3))) < 0) ? -(ABS(-2)-(ABS(-3))) : (ABS(-2)-(ABS(-3)))
```

`ABS(-3)` is surrounded by parentheses everywhere, so it is safely evaluated to `3`, so no need to expand it. So we end up:

```
(( ((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2) - 3) < 0) ? -(ABS(-2)-3) : (ABS(-2)-3)
```

`(ABS(-2)-3)` will expand to

```
((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2) - 3 = 2
```

Evaluating the whole:
`(( true ? 2 : -5 < 0) ? -2 : 2`
or

`(2 < 0) ? -2 : 2 = 2`
And it is the observed result, hope it is followable.

which is eno

Comment: But our question asked us for the output. How should I calculate the output?

Comment: Then I guess we should expand it.. Wait for an update.

Comment: Thanks man... let me try to understand it. I can't even believe this apeared in our exam!

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't parenthesized in the exam? I believe the desirable answer there was `1` ..

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the outer parenthesis, try this:

```
#define ABS(x) (((x) < 0) ? -(x) : (x))
```

Comment: This will indeed output 1, but the question is: why? hehe

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ABS(x) ((x) < 0) ? -(x) : (x))
int main()
{
    printf( "%d", ABS( ABS(-2) - ABS(-3) ) );
    return 0;
}
```

You forgot the closing right parenthesis `)` in your `#define`.

Also, `return` needs to be lowercase

I put spaces, so you can see the grouping more clearly.

Comment: It is not lacking a parenthesis

Comment: There is no missing parenthesis. You broke the code. That doesn't compile anymore.

Answer (score 1):

in http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59700f453a1dcaf9 with compile option -E

the gcc preprocessor has resolved this:

```
printf("%d\n", ABS(ABS(-2)-(ABS(-3))));
```

to this:

```
printf("%d\n", ((((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2)-(((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3))) < 0) ? -(((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2)-(((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3))) : (((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2)-(((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3))));
```

check it your self

Answer (score 1):

You need parenthesis around the expression that `ABS` defines. Instead of

```
#define ABS(x) ((x) < 0) ? -(x) : (x)
```

you need:

```
#define ABS(x) (((x) < 0) ? -(x) : (x))
               ^----------------------^
```

Without that, the expression `ABS(ABS(-2)-(ABS(-3)))` expands to:

```
((((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2)-(((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3))) < 0) ?  -(((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2)-(((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3))) : (((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2)-(((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3)))
```

That will be a tough one to analyze to understand what went wrong. However, if you look at the start of the expression, you will see that first term runs into the second term.

```
((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2)-(((-3) < 0) ...
                         ^^ (-2) Runs into the next term
```

The value of the expression is hard to predict. If you add parenthesis around the expression that the macro defines, you will see:

```
( (((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2)) - ( (((-3) < 0) ...
  ^ ------ one term ------- ^ There is no running in to the next term.
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's expand that macro out by hand:

```
ABS(-3) == ((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3)
ABS(-2) == ((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2)

ABS(-2) - ABS(-3) ==
  ((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2) - ((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3)
```

Now we have a problem: binary `-` has higher precedence than `?:`, so the above is being *parsed* as:

```
((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : 
  ((-2) - ((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3))
```

Since `(-2) < 0` is true, we evaluate `-(-2)`.  Then:

```
ABS( ABS(-2) - ABS(-3) ) ==
  ((((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2) - ((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3)) < 0 ?
    -(((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2) - ((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3)) :
    (((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2) - ((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3))
```

We've already established that

```
((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2) - ((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3)
```

evaluates to `2`, so the expression

```
(((-2) < 0) ? -(-2) : (-2) - ((-3) < 0) ? -(-3) : (-3))
```

gets evaluated, and, guess what?  It evaluates to `2`.

What you need to do is change your macro as follows:

```
ABS(x) ( (x) < 0 ? -(x) : (x) )
```

Then everything expands out as

```
ABS(-3) == ((-3) < 0 ? -(-3) : (-3))
ABS(-2) == ((-2) < 0 ? -(-2) : (-2))

ABS(-2) - ABS(-3) ==
  ((-2) < 0 ? -(-2) : (-2)) - ((-3) < 0 ? -(-3) : (-3))

ABS(ABS(-2) - ABS(-3)) ==
  (((-2) < 0 ? -(-2) : (-2)) - ((-3) < 0 ? -(-3) : (-3)) < 0 ?
    -(((-2) < 0 ? -(-2) : (-2)) - ((-3) < 0 ? -(-3) : (-3))) :
     ((-2) < 0 ? -(-2) : (-2)) - ((-3) < 0 ? -(-3) : (-3))
```

This time,

```
(((-2) < 0 ? -(-2) : (-2)) - ((-3) < 0 ? -(-3) : (-3))
```

evaluates to `-1`.

The rest should be clear from here.

You should *always* wrap expression macro bodies in an outer pair of parentheses for exactly this reason.